# Elegantly include dynamically generated code in Python package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I am writing a python package `foolib` which defines a class `foolib.Foo`. Creating a brand-new `Foo` object reads a `data_in` parameter and then performs an expensive numerical minimization, **unless the results of this minimization are also specified in the instantiation declaration**. Once this is done I can "export" this `Foo` instance by writing an instantiation declaration including the results of this minimization, which means that importing that exported code will not require performing the minimization once again:

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data_in, results = None):
        self.data_in = data_in
        if results is None:
            self.results = expensive_numerical_minimization(data_in)
        else:
            self.results = results

    def export(self, name, filename):
        with open(filename, 'w') as fid:
            fid.write(f'{name} = Foo({repr(self.data_in)}, {repr(self.results)})')
```

I'd like the user-facing code to look like this:

```py
from foolib.prebuilt import first_foo, second_foo
```

where `first_foo`, `second_foo` were pre-minimized prior to my package's release using the code below:

```py
from foolib import Foo

foo1 = Foo(123456) # takes a while
foo1.export('first_foo', 'foo1.py')

foo2 = Foo(345678) # takes a while
foo2.export('second_foo', 'foo2.py')
```

My problem is that I don't know how to cleanly import `foo1` and `foo2` into the submodule `foolib.prebuilt`, in a way that does not expose the `foo1.py` and `foo2.py` files themselves when using the package. Ideally, the only way to access the first pre-built instances would be through `foolib.prebuilt.first_foo` rather than through `foolib.foo1.first_foo`.

Is there an canonical, elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: It might be ultimately cleaner to either pickle the resulting object, or store the name/data/result (perhaps in JSON or YAML) and use some sort of factory method to specify from what name you want to instantiate.

Comment: I am trying to understand the scope of your task... Do you want to build *sdist* and *wheel* of this project, and distribute on *PyPI*? Do you want to compute those `Foo` instances once at build-time (when creating the *sdist*)? Or do you want to compute them at each run? Do you want to keep them on file? Where on file? Do you want to keep them as `.py` files or serialized in some other format?

Comment: @sinoroc, yes I'll build sdist+whl and distribute on PyPI. I want to compute the instances once at build-time and keep them on file, ideally as `.py` files because I want to make it very easy to inspect these instances, even for novice Python users, for open-science reasons.

Comment: Is the intent that the generated files depend on the environment (Python version, operating system, and so on), or will the generated files be the same for everyone?

Comment: For any given release, the generated files be the same for everyone.